# Rails: RuntimeError: Too many open files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, redis, sidekiq

Hi guys currently i'm running sidekiq in production, but in certain time so much jobs enter retries queue with error `RuntimeError: Too many open files`. Those jobs which is entering `retries` working with external API. When i restart the sidekiq by `capistrano` it works again. I have checked:

> current open files(`by using command lsof | wc -l`): 71088
>
> max open files(`by using command cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`): 400511

so it is clear that the culprit of this error is not caused by my app hits its file descriptor in production server(nginx ubuntu). Then some people say that culprit is coming from redis connection.Then i tested by using command to create a pair key, value in redis:

```
`2.2.1 :001 > REDIS = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)`

`=> #< Redis client v3.0.2 for redis://localhost:6379/0>`

`2.2.1 :002 > REDIS.set("hello", "goodbye")`

`=> "OK"`
```

Here is screen shot error from sidekiq which is running in production:[image]

The problem is when i restart my app by capistrano command (`cap production deploy`), there is no such error again, first i suspect it was caused by `redis` connection, but it is not. Then i suspected i caused by its file descriptor, but it is not. Could you guys help me to find the culprit of this error ? thank you guys

Comment: Any expert help me please?

Comment: Use lsof to list what's open in the process, you'll figure out what needs to be closed.

Comment: Hi @MikePerham, i've checked, yes there is so much open files by phantomjs, but when i tried to run command in each process by pid `lsof -p [pid]` it various returns open files, but the number belows limit of my ubuntu server that is 1024 (by run command `ulimit -n`), and the total of open files is still under maximum of system too, right now  i'm so frustated